# Barcode standards: is there a minimum size?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, barcodes

I'm coming to the end of a project with a client, we are just artworking and getting the standards correct. I have designed a label for a bottle, the label is fairly small, 150mm x 50mm so I have to be conscious about the label real estate.

I'm wondering if there a minimum size I MUST have the barcode or any standards that I must comply by? The client is located in New Zealand.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

First of all, download the standard. I think this is the one you need. Take a look at section 5.2.3.2: https://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/barcodes/GS1_General_Specifications.pdf

Second. These measurements depend on several things, the resolution of the print system, and some standards of how the laser beams operate.

Besides these guidelines, there are some other on how to accommodate the barcode, which depends on the package's shape and size.

Here is one on Spanish, but have some pictures :o) http://www.gs1py.org/docs/ManualUsuario2009.pdf

Try to find some specifics for NZ.

You need to see if there are some local regulations, not only for barcodes, but some other legal information, like nutrition facts, and Net content.

Google this terms and combinations: barcode standard guideline New Zeland.

---

On this image, (taken from CorelDraw code bar generator), you can see how the barcode is dependant on the print system used to actually print it (first mark)

[image]

I must say, you can play a bit with this sizes. Especially with the height of the barcode.

On the first image, you can also see that you can play a bit with the overall scaling.

If your flask is a small one, you can reduce it to some extent. On a closed environment, like barcode used for a local inventory, for example, you can reduce it, let's say yo 60% and make some tests with the actual reader you are going to use. (second mark on prev image)

On point 5.2.6.7 of the linked document, you can see some implied scaling. The table gives you some measurements of 80% scaling of the barcode.

Section 5.9 addresses the printing variables and the scanner's ones.

---

But you also can play with the height or crop a bit the top of the code bar.

This will not directly affect the "differentiation of the different" widths of the bars. It only will take more effort to the person scanning it.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Following up on Rafael's excellent answer, here's a link to a resource from the same international standards organisation, to a more current document (2015) in English: this, in combination with the first link in Rafael's answer should have you all sorted.

[**https://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/ten_steps_to_barcode_implementation.pdf**](https://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/ten_steps_to_barcode_implementation.pdf)

Also, as we here at GDSE prefer in-answer examples and content, and links only for reference, here's a screengrab from that document which may be helpful.

[image]

Hope this all helps mate.

Comment: The link is not working :(